# Footer overlap of bottom row

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm having trouble with my footer at the moment. I know that it is something very easy that I just havnt been able to notice. The problem occurs on the "more samples" page of http://www.hirelogo.com As you can see the last row is being covered. The problem is universal though which his the reason for no real footer on the main page as well. Any help would be much appreciated. Like i said before I know that this is probably an easy fix, but I just can't seem to figure it out. I am using joomla so the content area is not part of the header and footer scheme.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2):

The following changes seems to fix your issue.

In styles.css, around line 1376, remove the `position: absolute;` and the `width: 800px;`.  You will also need to add a `clear: both;`.  Here's how the final declaration will end up looking:

```
#footer {
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0; /* this line is no longer necessary either; see below */
    height: 63px;
    margin-top:1px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 103px;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

---

## Explanation:

In general, `position: absolute;` should be used only when you are planning to position something on the page that is separate from the flow of the page.  Since elements with `position: absolute;` don't take up any space on the page, when you were setting `bottom: 0;`, the div went to the bottom of the last element on the page, which caused it to overlap with the content div.

The `clear: both;` is necessary for the div to clear the floats that compose your rows in the content.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Unbelievably fast!

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `position:absolute` from `#footer` and the overlap will go away.

Comment: I can't believe how fast that was. Thanks so much Roddy! That loos like it did the trick. Now I can work out the footer. I knew it was something simple that I just wasn't using right or not including. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

You could change `position` of footer to `relative;` and adjust it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Unbelievably fast!

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this great gide to make footers go down :D

http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Unbelievably fast!